# Angular 2 'app-root' not loading on ExpressJS route

Tags: node.js, angular, express

Im new to NodeJS and Express but i want a simple '/' route to Angular's default  index.html (client/src/index.html) which contains the app-root tag.

The '/' route successfully serves the index.html file but it doesn't expand/load the 'app-root' tag into the component's html so i just get blank page.

Im not sure why it cant resolve the app-root tag when routed from Express. Only if i run Angular by 'ng serve' does the index.html successfully load the contents of the app-root tag.

My structure is as follows:

```
/client
    /e2e
    /node_modules
    /app
        app.component.css/html/ts
        app.module.ts
    /src
        index.html
        main.ts
package.json
server.js
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var port = 80;

var app = express();

// set static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client')));

app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/src/index.html');
});

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("Server started on port " + port);
});
```

Comment: You need to set something like on get app/root return that directory back to the request

Comment: What does your index.html file look like?

Comment: Sorry, can you show me what that would look like?

Comment: The Angular index.html is the default html template with just an app-root tag in body, and the component's html is the default template when you create a template

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It look like you didn't do 'ng build' your angular app because main.ts is still there.

When you do the 'ng serve', angular compiles and serve it using webpack-dev-server.

If you want to serve your app from the your node as static, you need a compiled angular app.

You can do the following

```
$ cd client && ng build
```

There will be client/dist directory created where your compiled angular app is located and you can serve that on your express

You can change the directory in you server.js like below

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/dist')));
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/dist/index.html');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Ahh i see, but once i get the dist folder and start the server in the folder i successfully get returned the index.html but its a blank html page with these errors: http://i.imgur.com/ocS7IMi.png

Comment: Actually, by changing 'app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client')));' to 'app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));' it works. What does this line do exactly? Does it load the files in the '/' directory so im able to use them?

Comment: express.static let you serve html and javascript files. Compiled angular files are now all just static html and javascript files that can be served on any web servers(nginx, apache, and in your case, Node serving static). If you haven't moved your dist files, then it could be because of angular-cli version. Have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37588470/angular-2-giving-an-error-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)